# Python code non-stop when processing text documents

Tags: python, nlp

I'm running the following code to process a list of documents, basically it's just two for loops.

```
from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from nlpia.loaders import get_data
word_vectors = get_data('w2v', limit=200000)

def tokenize_and_vectorize(dataset):
    tokenizer = TreebankWordTokenizer()
    vectorized_data = []
    expected = []
    for sample in dataset:
        tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sample[1])
        sample_vecs = []
        for token in tokens:
            try:
               sample_vecs.append(word_vectors[token])

            except KeyError:
               pass  

        vectorized_data.append(sample_vecs)
        #print(1)
    return vectorized_data
```

then I call the function to process the top 25k elements

```
vectorized_data=tokenize_and_vectorize(dataset[0:25000])
```

However, this code seems taking forever running as the * sign never disappear. (Note: I did try running only 50 samples and results came back pretty fast)

In order to see where it got stuck, I naively added `print(1)` ahead of `return vectorized_data` so for every cycle of loop it returns me a 1. After 1min36sec, I got all results returned.

A side observation of the computer memory usage. In the case without adding print(1), I did observe that the memory usage were high at the beginning and dropped back to normal level after couple mins, not sure if this indicates the process is done though * sign is still showing.

What caused this issue and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your dataset contains strings i.e. lines of text, a book, etc. Hence each of your lines is then broken up into words, which then are turned into word vectors.

It could be that your data takes a long time if your lines are very long or if you are trying to process a lot of lines at once.

Regarding your question what the '*' means (Source: [answer by Gopi Kumar](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98356995-d9e0-49d0-9a5f-31283dea6adc/jupyter-notebook-asterisk?forum=dsvm))

> An asterisk on Jupyter cell means that cell is still waiting to run.
>   Please check the preceding cells to see the one that is currently
>   running. It is possible you may have an error on one of the previous
>   cell. Also if you see a dark circle on the top right of the browser it
>   means a cell is still executing. A clear circle means it is idle.

Comment: Thank you PV. Maybe I didn't get my question clear. My concern is why after adding # print(1), code vectorized_data=tokenize_and_vectorize(dataset[0:25000]) will run, and without it, the code above will seemingly run forever.

Comment: @MeiNanZhu The short answer is, it doesn't run forever. But you are right that the '*' sign may stay next to the code block, and that has to do with an issue in Jupyter. I am not sure which version you are running, but see this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2748

Comment: Do you know there's a log file on the back end I can check what's going on in front end? I'm using Anaconda, and the python notebook version within is 6.0.2. Googled but no clear solution to follow.